# Trying to change a 3 way dimmer switch to a 3 way switch

Tags: electrical

See pictures the old 3 way dimmer no any screw can be seen except three wires out (two red and one black) and the box have two black wires and one red wire. Just confused which one can be the hot one and which two can be the travelers. So, please give me a hand. Thank you very much for your helping in advance

[image: 3 way dimmer switch]

[image]

Pictures about down stairs 3 way both side.
enter image description here Pictures about down stairs 3 way both side.

Comment: What make and model is said dimmer?

Comment: Something like Leviton 600W Single gang. But please note I don't need it replaced a new one, I really need to change to a simple 3 way switch instead of it. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a photo  of the wiring in the box please?

Comment: Actually I did get one pic about the wires in box but could not add to here. Tried many times and don't know why. I will try one more time right now

Comment: Great! I made it this time. Can you see it now?

Comment: You know what I checked the 3 way switch down stairs (Yes, that dimmer was used on the well up stairs, noticed that wires on one side is a red screwed and the other side are two black screwed separately. So, which could means that the red one in the box the hot (see picture) and the rest two black could be the travelers. Am I right? Gentleman.

Comment: Which wire is attached to the *differently colored screw* on the downstairs 3-way switch? (Ignore the green ground screw)

Comment: I can't see any differently colored screw. They are looked same color.

Comment: I tried to take photo of it but so far is dark there

Comment: So, all three screws on the 3-way switch downstairs are brass?! That's not right at all...

Comment: Sorry. Let me make sure to pull that switch out to watch carefully tomorrow morning. Its time to say good night now. thanks a lot for your time. Talk to you tomorrow.

Comment: Hi! Sir. I see this time the down stairs 3 way a screw up side is dark than others. Is this you said differently colored? Sorry, I post a picture about it but can't be seen this time.

Comment: Yes,two of the screws will be brass and one black. The messengers to to the brass.

Comment: Ok. I checked again the down stairs 3 way and for sure the left side up a screw much darker than the other two and a black wire screwed!

Answer (score 1):

Traveler wires are *two* wires. But the wires are interchangeable, and there is no need to distinguish one traveler from the other.

Working in conduit, I typically wire *travelers* as two wires of the same color.  When you're in a 3-way circuit and you see two yellow wires for instance going to the exact same place, those will be the travelers.

In your case the travelers are probably the two same-color wires on the switch.

When houses are wired in multiconductor cables, you are stuck with the default colors that those cables are manufactured with - black white red.  As such, you can't go by color code (unless you mark the wire with tape, paint or shrinkwrap).  **However, an important hint is that the *travelers* will both run in the same cable, and that will be true at both ends of the wire**.

Since your wiring is done with multiconductor cable, and none of your wires are white, and there must be two travelers: they must be red and black, and the black will be the one running in the same cable as the red.

Comment: So, you mean in my case the red one should be the hot and the two blacks should be travelers? Am I right? Sir.

Comment: As I said Yesterday the down stairs 3 way are one red and two black wires. I post pictures about it but can't be seen this time.

Comment: Sorry. I checked the down stairs 3 Way again and found out the left side up side screw is much dark than the other two! There is a black wire screwed. Is my case so complicated? Sir.

Comment: Not complicated.  The problem is placing importance on the wrong things: a) "physical position on the switch" is not important (actually, those positions vary, every switch is different) - what matters is **screw color**.  And b) "color of wires" is not important *but does provide hints* -- what matters is **grouping within cables**.    (A *cable* is several *wires* running together inside a common *sheath*.)

Comment: So, what you see in my case? Harper? Can I call your Harper? If right now I install a 3 way, which wire can be first screwed the dark one. The red? or the one of two blacks?

Comment: The red wire goes into the same cable with one of the blacks.  Which one?

Comment: Oh! Yea! That's the problem I met. Which black one?

Comment: You know I don't do replacement but change to a simple 3 way switch, right? That's it.

Comment: See my edit.  As a reminder, the two brass screws are for the travelers.

Comment: Ok. As you said what kind color of wires is not important. So, here in my case the one red and one black are travelers, they both will be screwed at the both sides and then the left one black has to be screwed the dark one. But the problem still is which black one can be sure for this position? As you had know that the dead dimmer doesn't has any screw can show me any hint.

Comment: I have explained this plainly, and you missed it.  Go **un-miss** it.  I will not repeat info, as this only confuses the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I just read this post while doing a similar replacement (old three-way dimmer switch with one black and two red wires, to be replaced by a "standard" 3-way switch).  In my case, the two red wires were the travelers.  I.e., the wires originally connected to them hooked up to the brass-colored screws on the replacement, and the wire connected to the black now connects to the darker colored screw on the replacement.